# See link when linked to image

Tags: html, css

So I made a clickable mail icon on my site. But the problem is the icon is clickable but I can see the link beside it, does anyone know why it still shows the link beside the icon? I am fairly new to `HTML` and `CSS` so I'm sorry if my code is messy.

[image: this is what I mean]

HTML code

```
<div id="social">
    <div id="images">
        <span class="twitter">
            <a href="https://www.twitter.com/powerjaxx" target="_blank"><img  src="img/Twitter_Social_Icon_Blue.png" alt="twitter" width="48" height="48"/></a>
        </span>
        <span class="twitch">
            <a href="https://twitch.tv/powerjaxx" target="_blank"><img src="img/Glitch_Purple_RGB.png" alt="twitch" width="48" height="48"/></a>
        </span>
        <span class="email">
            <a href="mailto:powerjaxx@gmail.com?subject=Contact" target="_blank"><img src="img/email-48.png" alt="email" width="48" height="48"/> </a>
        </span>
        <span class="github">
            <a href="https://github.com/PowerJaxx" target="_blank"><img src="img/GitHub-Mark-48px.png" alt="GitHub" width="48" height="48"/></a>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS code:

```
.social {
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 50px;

}

#social {
    font-family: 'robonto', sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-size: 1.9vw;
    letter-spacing: 5px;
    color: #FFFCFC;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}


#images {
    text-align: center;
}

.twitch {
    margin-right: 1vw;
    margin-left: 1vw;
}

.twitter {
    margin-right: 1vw;
    margin-left: 1vw;
}

.email {
    margin-right: 1vw;
    margin-left: 1vw;
}

.github {
    margin-right: 1vw;
    margin-left: 1vw;
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's funny. I've never seen this happen.

Your anchor tag has a space in it. It's the anchor tag in the "email" span tag.

try this:

```css
.social {
width: 100%;
margin-top: 50px;

}

#social {
font-family: 'robonto', sans-serif;
text-align: center;
font-size: 20px;
font-size: 1.9vw;
letter-spacing: 5px;
color: #FFFCFC;
margin-bottom: 0px;
}


#images {
text-align: center;
}

.twitch {

margin-right: 1vw;
margin-left: 1vw;
}

.twitter {

margin-right: 1vw;
margin-left: 1vw;
}

.email {

margin-right: 1vw;
margin-left: 1vw;
}

.github {

margin-right: 1vw;
margin-left: 1vw;
}
```

```html
    <div id="social">
    <div id="images">
 <span class="twitter">
 <a href="https://www.twitter.com/powerjaxx" target="_blank"><img  src="img/Twitter_Social_Icon_Blue.png" alt="twitter" width="48" height="48"/></a>
 </span>
   <span class="twitch">
   <a href="https://twitch.tv/powerjaxx" target="_blank"><img src="img/Glitch_Purple_RGB.png" alt="twitch" width="48" height="48"/></a>
   </span>
   <span class="email">
    <a href="mailto:powerjaxx@gmail.com?subject=Contact" target="_blank"><img src="img/email-48.png" alt="email" width="48" height="48"/></a>
  </span>
    <span class="github"><a href="https://github.com/PowerJaxx" target="_blank"><img src="img/GitHub-Mark-48px.png" alt="GitHub" width="48" height="48"/></a>
    </span>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It is happening, because the browser renders default styles for the a tag to remove that line add this class

```
a{
   text-decoration:none;
}
a:hover{
   text-decoration:none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add this in css

```
.github a { text-decoration:none; }
```

Make every anchor tag the same

Answer (score 1):

You want to remove the underline that is applied to anchor links:

```
#images a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Also: You have a space in your anchor tag, which creates the empty space with the underline.

Answer (score 0):

You can add just a single line in your css.

```
<Style>
 a{
    text-decoration:none;
  }
 a:hover{
    text-decoration:none;
  }
 </style>
```